# Product/Vendor/Price ORM

Tags: database, orm, product, sequelize.js, vendor

Using sequelize.
we have Products and Vendors and we need to make a new relation VendorProduct that has price and date of that price

how do you translate this relation to sequelize ORM?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you read the [sequelize documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/)?

Comment: yes. i finally redesigned the models. I now have Price, Vendor, Product, User models. Price.belongsTo(Vendor), Price.belongsTo(User), Price.belongsTo(Product)